# Query string databind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to bind data to a label when it is the same as the query string that I have.
I keep getting a error saying.

Must declare the scalar variable "@YouthClubID".

Here is my code.

```
      using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class youthclubpage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int YouthClubID;

       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("server = sql7.hostinguk.net; uid = joanton7865org7272_phelim; pwd = Armo32nk; database = joanton7865org7272_youthpodcast;"))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                string strSQL = "Select youthclubname from youthclublist WHERE ([YouthClubID] = @YouthClubID)";
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YouthClubID", Request.QueryString["club"]);
                    txtClubName.Text = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() + "";
                }
            }
        }
        }


    }
```

Comment: you should redact the connection information in your question before posting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happens, as others said already, because you're not populating the Parameter defined in the SQL statement.

Anyway, you don't need Adapter at all, in your case [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method is enough:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    string strSQL = "Select youthclubname from youthclublist WHERE ([YouthClubID] = @YouthClubID)";
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YouthClubID", Request.QueryString["club"]);
        txtClubName.Text = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() + "";
    }
}
```

In the above I assumed the club ID is passed as `page.aspx?club=[id here]` meaning the query string variable name is "club", change to the real  name of course.

The `+ ""` part is meant to put empty text in case there is no matching value in database.
When there is no such value, `sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` will return *null* - having the plain way of:

```
txtClubName.Text = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Will generate error in such case - by adding empty string the conversion to string occurs automatically and it looks more pretty. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637308/c-why-is-adding-null-to-a-string-legal) as well. Needless to say, if the value *is not null*, it won't be changed.

Comment: I'm not sure of the purpose of `+ ""` at the end of the `ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: Cheers thats helped explain the reason

Comment: When i use this code i get the following error. The parameterized query '(@YouthClubID nvarchar(4000))Select youthclubname from youthclub' expects the parameter '@YouthClubID', which was not supplied.

Comment: @Inkey so you didn't copy it properly. Post your new code and I'll try to see what you done wrong.

Comment: @Inkey this means `Request.QueryString["club"]` is null - how your query string looks like? I was just guessing with "club".

Comment: heres my query string
<li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("youthclubname") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "youthclubpage.aspx?CategoryID=" + Eval("YouthClubID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>

Comment: @Inkey So change `Request.QueryString["club"]` to `Request.QueryString["CategoryID"]`. That's what I meant in *meaning the query string variable name is "club", change to the real name of course.*

Answer (score 0):

You're using a Variable in your SQL Statement, that you have do define/ set in your C# code.

```
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(<ConnectionString>);
sqlCommand = new _SQLCli.SqlCommand("Select youthclubname from youthclublist WHERE ([YouthClubID] = @YouthClubID)",sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters
                         .Add(new _SQLCli.SqlParameter( "@YouthClubID", <neededValue>);)
            sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("...");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select youthclubname from youthclublist WHERE ([YouthClubID] = @YouthClubID)", sqlConnection);
command.Parameters.Add("@YouthClubID", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@YouthClubID"].Value = clubID;

SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add the parameters to your command object.  [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx), 
try like this . a your returning only one value from db, you can use ExecuteScalar method

```
  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    // Create the SelectCommand.
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Select youthclubname from youthclublist WHERE ([YouthClubID] = @YouthClubID)", sqlConnection);

    // Add the parameters for the SelectCommand.
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YouthClubID", yourYouthClubID);
    yourClubName = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```