# How come this code is valid C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, string, null, concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Why is adding null to a string legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637308/c-why-is-adding-null-to-a-string-legal)

Here is the valid C# code:

```
var samsung= "xyz" + null + null + null + null + "890";  // xyz890
```

And this is the invalid C# code:

```
var iphone= null.ToString(); // compiler error
```

Why and how is the first statement valid and second is invalid ?

Comment: You cant change `nothing`(here which is null)

Comment: Wonder if the null additions are removed by the compiler?  Anyone know?

Comment: @GrantH. if they are null constants then yes.  In fact the whole expression is simplified to `"xyz890"` in IL.

Comment: @GrantH. They are, but technically it won't change the result, just the performance.  If it didn't evaluate it to a single constant at compile time (you could trivially change this to prevent it from being able to do that) then it would still work, and if it couldn't run it at runtime then it wouldn't be able to optimize it at compile time.  In other words, the compile time optimization doesn't change the explanation of why this does or doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator is used to concatenate strings, and since `null` is an instance of the string class it can be used as an argument to the operator. `"xyz" + null`  ends up returning the string "xyz", so this process is just repeated until you actually add `"890"`.

While null can be used as a string object for an argument to a method, you cannot actually call methods on it because there's nothing to process the method call.

Think of methods as a way for an object to process an external request and things make a bit more sense. You can send a request to an object with `null` as an argument for what to process, but you can't actually ask `null` to process something.

Comment: This is really good explaination too. Thankss !

Comment: _"`null` is an instance of the string class ..."_ No, it's not an instance in any way. It's an expression which can be interpreted, in some cases, as having type `string`. In this case you can also interprete it as being `(object)null`; the result is the same. But a null reference is no instance, it is lack of instance.

Answer (score 1):

The C# compiler thinks of null in concatenations as an empty string.

```
 var samsung= "xyz" + null + null + null + null + "890";
```

equals

```
 var samsung= "xyz" + ""+ ""+ ""+ ""+ "890";
```

When you try to call `null.toString()` you are essentially trying to call a method on a null object, which (if it compiled) would always cause a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

With the first line, you are concatinating strings.  `null` is nothing, so essentially you are getting `xyz890`.  It's like doing `1+0+0+0+4` But with your second, you're call `ToString()` on a `null`.  `null` is nothing, so there's nothing there to call `ToString()` on.  You're attempting to call a method on an non-initialized variable.

Comment: Ohhh makes sense to me now! Thanks a lot guys :-) My question is answered.

Comment: @user1688826 If your question is answered, you should accept an answer

Comment: While this isn't wrong, you don't actually explain why you can concat null with a string using `operator +`, you just say *that* you can.  Running his code already told him that much...

Comment: @Servy: I gave the example of `1+0+0+0+4` as an example.  Was hoping it was the concept would be understood.

Comment: @TyrionLannister The *concept* is irrelivant here.  Logically it might make sense for null concatted with "abc" to be abc, but note that `null.Concat("abc")` results in a null pointer exception.  What makes that different from `null + "abc"` which works as expected without error?  That's what your answer should explain to actually answer the question.  Again, it's not wrong, it just skips over the part of the question that's actually important.

Answer (score 1):

Since `string` is a reference type, null can be implicitly converted to `string`. And in first case sequence of `+` operators just is transformed to `String.Concat(obj1, obj2, obj3, ...)`

To make your code compile you can call `Convert.ToString`:

```
var iphone = Convert.ToString(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the `+` operator as a global static function like so:

```
+(string leftHandSide, string rightHandSide) {
  if (leftHandSide == null)
     leftHandSide = string.Empty;
  if (rightHandSide == null)
     rightHandSide = string.Empty;
  string returnValue;

  // concatenate string

  return returnValue;
}
```

Since this string concatenation method is static it does not require an instance to call it, it handles the null values. However when you try to call `ToString` on `null` there is no instance of an object so there is no `ToString` mehthod to call, hence the exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. You could read the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx). Quote:

> String concatenation:
>
> ```
> string operator +(string x, string y);
> string operator +(string x, object y);
> string operator +(object x, string y);
> ```
>
> These overloads of the binary `+` operator perform string concatenation.
>   If an operand of string concatenation is `null`, an empty string is
>   substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its
>   string representation by invoking the virtual `ToString` method
>   inherited from type `object`. If `ToString` returns `null`, an empty string
>   is substituted.
>
> [...]

So, as others have said, think of `+` as a kind of method that takes in two arguments and is OK with one or both of them being `null`.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Because you can't call a method on a `null` reference in any case, so the compiler doesn't allow it.</strike>  In your first case, the compiler will pre-compile the string constant to `"xyz890"` so it is a legal assignment.

In general, the `+` operator for `string` compiles to `String.Concat(s1, s2, ...)` which supports `null` arguments.

To be more precise on the second case, the actual problem isn't that it's a null pointer, it's that there is no *type* to bind the method to.  As pointed out in other comments, you can cast `null` to any reference type and it compiles just fine:

```
((string)null).ToString();   // compiles, but fails at run-time.
```

Answer (score 0):

The + operator will be translated to a static function that looks much like:

```
public static string Concat(string first, string second) {...}
```

Passing null as a parameter to a function isn't a problem; it gets passed just fine.  That function happens to check that neither of the parameters are null before concatting them; if any of the parameters are null they are treated as empty strings so as to not cause exceptions.  The key point here is that no instance members of the strings are called until they are first null checked by this function.

As for `null.ToString()` calling an instance function on anything that evaluates to `null` at compile time results in an exception.  This is the very definition of that case.

Comment: Good explanation. Just a technical detail: Writing `null.ToString()` gives the compile-time error: _CS0023: Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type '<null>'_ However, if you help a little with the type, as in `((string)null).ToString()`, it will compile fine and you get your `NullReferenceException` run-time.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the IL you'll see that the compiler is smart enough to just drop the null values and creates a concatenated string.  As mentioned earlier you can't do a null.ToString(); you can do string.Empty or assign a string to be null.

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] string samsung)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "xyz890"        //null has been removed by compiler.  
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

**EDIT**
Expand on Nielson's comment.  As null represents an nil reference it might be fair to say that the way string concat is handled is C# permits such as operation.  I'd fathom it uses byte array building which would omit the null values, thus simply making it appear as if it's concating null.

Comment: I think the Original Poster is asking **why** it's legal. It's a technical detail that the compiler performs the complete operation (five plusses) by itself _compile-time_ and only emits the correct "sum" in its IL output.