# String.ToString() method on null String Object

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, tostring

I have the following code:

```
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            var obj=(person)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(person));
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
    }
     public class person
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public DateTime dob { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return id.ToString() + " " + name + " " + dob.ToString();
            }
        }
}
```

which yields the following output:

```
0  1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

However, if change the `person.ToString()` to the following:

```
public override string ToString()
{
        return id.ToString() + " " + name.ToString() + " " + dob.ToString();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Rextester.person.ToString()
```

Can someone shed some light on it.

Edited

Comment: 1) So...how is that line different than your code above? 2) Why are you using `Activator` and not just the constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Why not just use the default constructor for `person`? Also I can't tell what you changed.

Comment: @SamLeach No, it's not.  The stack trace alone proves that.

Comment: Please edit your answer to tell use what change you really made to Person.ToString. Without that, it's hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your code samples aren't correct as it stands in your question and you're actually seeing this behavior:

```
return id.ToString() + " " + name + " " + dob.ToString();
```

**works**

```
return id.ToString() + " " + name.ToString() + " " + dob.ToString();
```

**doesn't work**

This is because adding a null *value* to a string is legal but calling a method on a null *instance* is not.

See this question:
[Why is adding null to a string legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637308/c-why-is-adding-null-to-a-string-legal)

Comment: @Servy - it's not the code he's posted, but clearly the code he's posted is not right since it's identical to the first version. nvuono's guess at what was intended makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @hatchet There are any number of things that could be done instead as well.  Rather than guessing, it's more productive to simply wait for the OP to edit his *real* code in.