# StringBuilder, append string if conditions are met

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

```
var sb = new StringBuilder ();

if (condition1) sb.Append ("one");
if (condition2) sb.Append ("two");
if (condition3) sb.Append ("three");
if (condition4) sb.Append ("four");
if (condition5) sb.Append ("five");

return sb.ToString ();
```

Any idea how to improve it? How to write less code, giving same result?

Comment: This looks fine already. You could probably create an extension method, something like `AppendIf(string, bool)`, but not sure if this is an improvement at all

Comment: if there is no inter-dependency between the conditions, I see no way to improve things.

Comment: use a single varible and at the end just append it

Comment: You could do `sb.Append(condition1 ? "One" : "");` but I'm not sure it's any better.

Comment: Just to note, there is [another site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to this sort of question.

Comment: @BhargavModi, what if multiple conditions are true?

Comment: @Jodrell than just use `(confition1 || condition2)`

Answer (score 15):

This code is fine. Keep it like this.

- Every attempt to use extension methods or others will only make this code less understandable and maintainable;
- There is no repeating code;
- As long as the conditions don't influence another, there is no way of shortening the `if`s.

If you do want another option:

```
string s = 
   (condition1 ? "one" : null) + 
   (condition2 ? "two" : null) + 
   (condition3 ? "three" : null) + 
   (condition4 ? "four" : null) + 
   (condition5 ? "five" : null)
   ;
```

But let's be honest, does this make it better? No.

Comment: you should use `string.Empty` instead of `""`

Comment: Just wondering - if all conditions are `false`, will this code result in a null string rather than an empty string?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: No. `""`. String concatenation will always result in an instantiated `string`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks.  Now off to investigate why that is...! ... ([here's the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/637320/791010))

Answer (score 7):

I prefer approach with simple DSLs definition, when it makes code simpler or more readable. Also "pipeline-style" expressions are awesome.
In your case it can be written like this:

```
var str =
    new StringBuilder()
        .AppendIf(condition1, "one")
        .AppendIf(condition2, "two")
        .AppendIf(condition3, "forty two")
        .ToString();
```

With an extension method.

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
    public static StringBuilder AppendIf(
        this StringBuilder @this,
        bool condition,
        string str)
    {
        if (@this == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("this");
        }

        if (condition)
        {
            @this.Append(str);
        }

        return @this;
    }
}
```

Approach is suitable here, if conditions are repeated. For example `arg1 != null`, `arg2 != null`, then `AppendIfNotNull` can be used.

Otherwise, think twice, because it looks quite similar to initial implementation, requires additional code, can be slower because of additional null checks and method invocations, and also you should create an `AppendIf` overload for every `Append` one.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like,

```
var conditions = new[]
    {
        Tuple.Create(condition1, "one"),
        Tuple.Create(condition2, "two"),
        Tuple.Create(condition3, "three"),
        Tuple.Create(condition4, "four"),
        Tuple.Create(condition5, "five"),
    }

return string.Concat(conditions.Where(t => t.Item1).Select(t => t.Item2));
```

Is that better? No.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use string interpolation like documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated. So, the example can be modified like this. I think it is easier to read.

```
var s = $"{(condition1 ? "one": null)}{(condition2 ? "two": null)}{(condition3 ? "three": null)}{(condition4 ? "four": null)}{(condition5 ? "five": null)}";
```

Edit:
You can make the code easier to read by making it verbatim string literal.

```
var s = $@"{
    (condition1 ? "one": null)
}{
    (condition2 ? "two": null)
}{
    (condition3 ? "three": null)
}{
    (condition4 ? "four": null)
}{
    (condition5 ? "five": null)}";
```